# GCC linked static library failed

Tags: gcc, hyperlink

I tried to use gcc command to link a static library, but it didn't work.

[image]

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Copy-paste the actual test into the body of the question. you might also want to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the `-l` flag command to link your application like so:

```
gcc t.c -L. -lt1.a -o t
```

Then your .a archive needs to have a filename of `libt1.a` not just `t1.a`.

When using `-lsome_name` to link in a library, the linker will look for a file named `libsomename.so` or `libsomename.a`

If you do not want to rename your .a archive, you can also just do

```
gcc t.c t1.a -o t
```

<sub>also, in the future please don't post an image of your code or commands, just copy paste it as text into your post</sub>

Comment: probelom solved, but when I tried to add param ‘-static’ ，I got "ld: library not found for -lcrt0.o" error

Comment: @Rickard Ok, but you should ask a new question about that if you need help.

Answer (score 0):

Libraries in POSIX environments (like Linux and OSX) are usually named in the pattern `lib<name of library>.a`. When you link with the library you *either* use the `-l` option and only use `<name of library>` and the linker will automatically add the `lib` prefix and `.a` suffix. *Or* you don't use the `-l` option and istead give the whole file-name verbatime.

Since you don't use the standard naming scheme for the libraries, you can't use the `-l` option and instead have to explicitly use the library file, similar to

```
$ gcc ... t1.a
```

If you want to use the `-l` option you have to name your library `libt1.a` and only use `t1` when linking:

```
$ gcc ... -L. -lt1
```

Comment: probelom solved, but when I tried to add param ‘-static’ ，I got "ld: library not found for -lcrt0.o" error